# custom error page for failed client certificate authentication in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, authentication, ssl

I am already running a web application, which access control is configured with client certificate authentication (CLIENT-CERT). Users can login with their certificates and access is granted. Fine.

If no valid client certificate is presented to tomcat, the connection is closed with this browser error: *ssl_error_bad_cert_alert*. By reloading the page no second try is possible.

I think it is difficult to explain normal users, that they have to restart their browser in case of an authentication error. Maybe there is no other way as restarting the browser.

But can I display an custom error page in case of an certificate authentication error or can the request redirected to a none restricted page?

Best regards Johannes

Comment: I have the exact same question for some time now, but I have only seen people saying it is not possible. But am certainly interested in a solution if there is one.

Comment: The [form fallback](https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/SSLWithFORMFallback) is no real solution, but I'm fine with that.